# Prevent switching to the invoking activity via long-pressing the Home button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

An application starts (for result) an activity from another application.

Everything works, but the user is able to switch to the calling activity by long-pressing the Home button and choosing that activity. Logically, this is wrong, and the calling activity must not receive control until the invoked activity finishes.

How do I fix this? (Preferably, on the calling application side.)

Currently the code reads:

```
final String INTENT_NAME = "com.xyz.xyz.GET_XXX";
//...
Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_NAME);
intent.putExtra("something", something()); // app-specific
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

What is desired:

The calling activity is postponed until the called activity terminated. The user cannot switch to the calling activity before the called activity is finished (preferably, the task switcher should not even show it as an option). After the called activity is finished, it is the calling activity that receives control.

What is currently there:

It is possible to switch to the calling activity without finishing the called activity.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix this?

You rewrite your app to fix your design flaw.

Starting another activity is like linking to another Web site. The user can do whatever the user wants, given that link:

- Click the link, do something, and return to your site via some forward operation (e.g., submitting a form that causes a server redirect to your site)
- Click the link, do nothing, and return to your site via the BACK button
- Click the link, do nothing, and not return to your site at all (e.g., close the browser tab)

You have similar results with `startActivityForResult()`:

- The user is welcome to return to your app via BACK or RECENTS (a.k.a., long-pressing HOME)
- The user is welcome to never return to your app
- The user is welcome to do what you were hoping they'd do in the other activity

You have no means of controlling the user in this regard. Hence, your application needs to be implemented to be OK with any of those possible outcomes. Or, your application needs to be rewritten to not use `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: There is no design flaw, the application does not crash. OTOH, the activities defined in the same application do not all show in the task switcher, and I want the same behavior.

Comment: @18446744073709551615: Since only one thumbnail per task is shown in the task switcher, I do not know what you mean by "the activities defined in the same application do not all show in the task switcher". And your comment makes no sense with respect to your question, where you specifically state that you are trying to attack the user by controlling their behavior: "The user cannot switch to the calling activity before the called activity is finished (preferably, the task switcher should not even show it as an option)".